# Can't Login to cPanel with C# WebRequest

Tags: c#, authentication, cpanel

I am struggling to develop a C# class to login to cPanel on a web host (Hostgator).

In PHP it is quite easy using the Curl extension as follows:

```
$url = "http://mysite.com:2082/";

$c = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:password');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($c);
if ($result === false)
    $result = curl_error($c);
curl_close($c);

file_put_contents('log.txt', $result);
//print_r($result);
```

Now here is my C# class with the various attempts to make it work commented out:

```
class HTTPHandler
{
    public static string Connect (string url, string userName, string password)
    {
        string result;

        try
        {
            // An initial @ symbol in the password must be escaped
            if (password.Length > 0)
                if (password[0] == '@')
                    password = "\\" + password;

            // Create a request for the URL.        
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

            /*
            var credCache = new CredentialCache();
            credCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic",
                              new NetworkCredential(userName, password));
            request.Credentials = credCache;
            */

            //request.Method = "POST";
            //request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            /*
            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = string.Format("user={0}&pass={1}", userName, password);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();
            */

            // Get the response.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Display the content.
            result = string.Format("Server response:\n{0}\n{1}", response.StatusDescription, reader.ReadToEnd());
            // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = string.Format("There was an error:\n{0}", e.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

But I keep getting an error 401 (Unauthorized) at the GetResponse stage.

When I compare the $_SERVER vars in my local host test page between the PHP and C# submissions, I get the same data apart from the sender port being a bit different. The crucial PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PW are the same.

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit and I am using Visual C# 2010.

I guess the solution is really simple, but so far I am baffled. But a relative newbie to C#. I hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to set `PreAuthenticate`, just let the request figure it out. Also I would suggest using `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebRequest`. The main difference is that you can set `CookieContainer` property to enable cookies. This is a bit confusing since by default it will have cookies disabled and all you need to do is to set it to `new CookieContainer();` to enable cookies for your request.
This matters because of the redirects that happen during authentication and the auth cookie that records the fact that you successfully authenticated.

Also a coding style note: please make sure to wrap all the `IDisposable`s (such as response, stream and reader) in the `using()` statement.

Also I am unclear why are you escaping `@` in the password. Request should take care of all your encoding needs automagically.

Complete sample code:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); // needed to enable cookies

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet)))
    return string.Format("Server response:\n{0}\n{1}", response.StatusDescription, reader.ReadToEnd());
```

edit: Sorry for all the edits. I was writing code by memory and was struggling a bit with getting the encoding part right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With my test page on the local server I was not receiving the username and password details to the PHP page without using PreAuthenticate. And with Curl I wasn't needing to use cookies. I found that I had to escape the initial @ character when connecting to cPanel with PHP and Curl before.

Comment: Hopefully somebody that has Linux hosting with cPanel can test out some C# code that succesfully logs in. It has nothing to do with cookies since you have to make it past the GetResponse stage without an error. Just emulate my PHP example.

Comment: Thanks for you help but it didn't work for me. However, I found a solution, you have to force the http authentication, rather than having the web page ask for the credentials. Check out: [link](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Forcing-basic-http-authentication-for-HttpWebReq.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is using System.Web where I had to set the project properties to use the full .NET Framework 4 to gain access to this assembly for the HttpUtility and add a reference to System.Web in References.

I didn't test all the overloaded methods but the main thing is the cPanel connection where the authentication credentials are added to the http header when a userName is present.

Also, for cPanel I needed to set request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; so that I control page by page access since I didn't manage to capture cookies.

Here is the code for the HTTP Helper Class that I came up with:

```
class HTTPHandler
{
    // Some default settings
    const string UserAgent = "Bot"; // Change this to something more meaningful
    const int TimeOut = 1000; // Time out in ms

    // Basic connection
    public static string Connect(string url)
    {
        return Connect(url, "", "", UserAgent, "", TimeOut);
    }

    // Connect with post data passed as a key : value pair dictionary
    public static string Connect(string url, Dictionary<string, string> args)
    {
        return Connect(url, "", "", UserAgent, ToQueryString(args), TimeOut);
    }

    // Connect with a custom user agent specified
    public static string Connect(string url, string userAgent)
    {
        return Connect(url, "", "", userAgent, "", TimeOut);
    }

    public static string Connect(string url, string userName, string password, string userAgent, string postData, int timeOut)
    {
        string result;

        try
        {
            // Create a request for the URL.        
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            if (userAgent == null)
                userAgent = UserAgent;

            request.UserAgent = userAgent;
            request.Timeout = timeOut;

            if (userName.Length > 0)
            {
                string authInfo = userName + ":" + password;
                authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
                request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
                request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            }

            if (postData.Length > 0)
            {
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }
            }

            // Get the response.
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    result = string.Format("Server response:\n{0}\n{1}", response.StatusDescription, reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = string.Format("There was an error:\n{0}", e.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string ToQueryString(Dictionary<string, string> args)
    {
        List<string> encodedData = new List<string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in args)
        {
            encodedData.Add(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Key) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pair.Value));
        }

        return String.Join("&", encodedData.ToArray());
    }
}
```